# Unable to show taskbar when focus on application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, taskbar

I wrote a WPF application, and when it is opened and focused, I cannot show the taskbar when my cursor hovers on the bottom edge (the taskber is auto-hidden), regardless of whether the application is maximized or re-sized to a smaller dimension. I have to manually click the "Window" start button on the keyboard to show the taskbar (of course that also show the start menu as well).

I found a similar question being asked in SO - [Auto hide taskbar not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137005/auto-hide-taskbar-not-appearing-when-my-application-is-maximized) - but in my case the taskbar still won't show even if it's not maximized, and I did not override the `MINMAXINFO` record. The XAML of application MainWindow is as simple as this:

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow x:Class="MySoftware.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        Title="My Software" Icon="Images\myLogo.ico"
        x:Name="MainWindow1" Background="#FFE8E8E8" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a `RibbonWindow`, the problem most probably lies there. I am doing something similar using a third-party control, and submitted a bug report, which was then later fixed.